# For further research: terminology about manipulating command before hitting RET in terminal

Tags: terminal, zsh

I just found out in zsh if I have a variable, namely `abc="cba"`, and if I type `echo ${!abc}` and pressing enter, it doesnt go as command but instead open new prompt below with expanded variable `echo ${abc="cba"}`.

And probably included that powerful zsh plugin that let us automatically insert `sudo` just by double tapping `Esc`.

So for further studying and probably opening new possibilities, what is the right terminology about that typed-command-but-not-entered manipulation?

Thanks...

Comment: Those seem to be unrelated. The first is zsh asking you to [verify history expansion](https://superuser.com/a/714471/334516). The second is a keybinding that uses [ZLE to modify the current command line](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Widgets).

Comment: @muru whoaaa this should be in formal answer. Thankss...

Answer (score 0):

Those seem to be unrelated. The first is zsh asking you to [verify history expansion](https://superuser.com/a/714471/334516). The second is [a ZLE (Zsh Line Editor) widget](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Widgets) with a keybinding to modify the current command line. You can see what this ZLE widget looks like in [oh-my-zsh the source code](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/sudo/sudo.plugin.zsh).